# Angular 4 httpd post call fails in iOS

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am having a weird problem in a POST call in iOS using Nativescript and Angular 4. I have tested the same code in Android and works perfect. The server does not register any error but the call fails. This is the code I am using right now:

```
...
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
...

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
let body = 
    "Username=" + this.username 
    +"&Password=" + this.password;
this.http.post("http://myserver.com/api/login", body, options)
    .map(result => result.json())
    .subscribe(
        result => {
            this.loader.hide();
            if (result.Authenticated) {
                // Do something...
            }
            else {
                Dialogs.alert({title: 'Error', message: "Username and/or password are incorrect.", okButtonText: "Close"});
            }
        }, 
        error => {
            Dialogs.alert({title: 'Error', message: "There was an error trying to send the request, please try again later.", okButtonText: "Close"});
        }
    )
```

The app shows me `There was an error trying to send the request, please try again later.` message, but there is no error in the server and the curious thing is that Android works fine.

I have enabled the `enableProdMode()` in Angular and no luck.

Any help please?

Thanks!

Comment: so the call never reaches the server on ios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were having crashing and hanging issues on Nativescript iOS + *http* connections until yesterday. We switched to *https* connections for our servers' API and everything is working perfectly now.

Maybe it has something to do with the secure / non secure connections on iOS?

Try switching to a secure connection and see what happens.

If you can't do that, try adding this to your info.plist file to allow http connections:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thats exactly what is going on, I changed the protocol to http and worked in iOS, now its time to decide if we switch to https or keep http and include that rule. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It seems iOS 11 won't allow http connections, so I think going the https way is a safe bet.

Comment: One more thing, I tried to run a https call in Android and got lots of errors, one of them is:

System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure, we did the change and nothing got broken on Android thankfully.

Try removing the hooks and node_module folders, and running tns install / npm install / tns run android again?

Comment: I got the same error with @relez and haven't found a way to resolve it.